# Trying to understand the Promise in angular 2

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-promise, observable

I have created a service for google API and stacked at the promise response. Let me show you my code:

```
getPromise: Promise<any>;
loadSheets: Array<any>;

constructor(public _checkAuthApiService: CheckAuthApiService) { }

ngOnInit() {
    if (this._checkAuthApiService) {
        this._checkAuthApiService.checkAuth().then(res => {
            if (res && !res.error) {
                this.loadSheetsFunc();
            }
        });
    }

    //setTimeout(function(){},1000); //When i add this it works :(
}

loadSheetsFunc = () => {
    this.getPromise = new Promise((resolve: any, reject: any) => {
        resolve(this._checkAuthApiService.loadSheetsApi())
    });
    this.getPromise.then((res: any) => this.sheetsResults(res));
};

sheetsResults = (res: any) => this.loadSheets = res.result.values;
```

not sure what i am missing but when i add `seTimeout` within `ngOnInit` ti works i get the data i want on the view. Can someone help me with this code or perhaps suggest me a better way using Observables. Thank you in advance.

Comment: What does `this._checkAuthApiService.loadSheetsApi` do?

Comment: Do you use some promise polyfill?

Comment: this._checkAuthApiService.loadSheetsApi is returning the sheet data from google api. In the end res.result.values contains the data i need but since is async call the data are available later in time,  i am testing it using the setTimeout above and it works , i get what i need. The problem remains at the promise call which is not firing properly or i am missing something.

Comment: Why do you use `new Promise()` in `loadSheetsFunc()`?

Answer (score 0):

The `setTimeout()` causes a full Angular2 change detection cycle, which is why this makes Angular2 recognize the updated property.

That Angular2 doesn't recognize the update without `setTimeout()` indicates an issue with polyfills (perhaps loading order).

I would make a few changes to your code

```
loadSheets: Array<any>;

constructor(public _checkAuthApiService: CheckAuthApiService) { }
ngOnInit() {
    if (this._checkAuthApiService) {
        this._checkAuthApiService.checkAuth().then(res => {
            if (res && !res.error) {
                this.loadSheetsFunc();
            }
        });
    }
}

loadSheetsFunc() {
    this._checkAuthApiService.loadSheetsApi()
    subscribe(val => this.sheetsResults(res));
}

sheetsResults(res: any) {
    this.loadSheets = res.result.values;
}
```

I don't know though what `loadSheetsApi()` returns (assuming `Observable`).